# Trigger React Listener from .NetCore Project

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, session, cookies, webapi

I am creating a project which uses React at frontend and .NetCore at backend. I can call my .net core rest services from react. But in current condition I need to do reverse call. I mean I need to trigger a react event from .net core. I tried to do this with cookies. But I had problem with accesing cookies because of different sessions. Is there a better way to trigger a function in a react project from .net core?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can call my .net core rest services from react. But in current condition I need to do reverse call.

You can try to integrate SignalR with your project, which enables us to call JavaScript functions on clients from server-side .NET Core code.

To achieve it, you could implement SignalR Hub with methods on backend and SignalR client functionality on React frontend.

For more information about ASP.NET Core SignalR, please check following official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Just finished implementing it to my project. And it works very well.